# WMS GetPrint doesn't publish any layers

Tags: wms, qgis-server, getprint

I am using QGIS-server (2.14) for publishing online maps and everything seems to work fine except for the output of the GetPrint request.

Indeed, only the scale, the title and the label of the legend is displayed but not the map realized in the print composer (QGIS 2.14).

In the GetProjectSettings response, I have my print templates but the URL that I use (based on the QGIS documentation and tested under Chrome and Firefox):

`http://myserver.com/cgi/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?...&REQUEST=GetPrint&TEMPLATE=myprintcomposername&map0:EXTENT=xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax&FORMAT=pdf&DPI=300&`

Didn't display my layers/map cf.

[image]

Do you have any idea to fix the problem?

Comment: Perhaps there is a maximum width/height limit on the server. Printing needs better resolution than screen and therefore the preview can work even printing does not. From http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_server_support.html: `you can restrict the maximum size of the maps returned by the GetMap request by entering the maximum width and height into the respective fields under Maximums for GetMap request`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried it but it doesn't change anything. I have the same result.

Comment: A further test could be to make the same request with &DPI=72. If result is still the same there is obviously something else going on.

Comment: Yes, it is the same. I already tried that :-(

Comment: Have you tried other formats than pdf?

Comment: Yes, same result with png. Just for information with GetMap request everything is ok

Comment: Hello, Im also using a qgiswebserver with the client, and when exporting print I make the following request: http://mysrvr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=myproject.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3&REQUEST=GetPrint&FORMAT=pdf&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&TRANSPARENT=true&SRS=EPSG:XXXX&DPI=300&TEMPLATE=TemplateName%201&map0:extent=12345.6,12345.3,45678.3,12345.7&map0:rotation=0&map0:scale=75000&map0:grid_interval_x=5000&map0:grid_interval_y=5000&LAYERS=EnterLayersHere. I will also form this into an answer so its more readable

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your layers are not defined in the request therefore you need to add their names to the request, so the composer will display them.

```
mysrvr/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=myproject.qgs&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3&REQUEST=GetPrint&FORMAT=pdf&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&TRANSPARENT=true&SRS=EPSG:XXXX&DPI=300&TEMPLATE=TemplateName&map0:extent=12345.6,12345.3,45678.3,12345.7&map0:rotation=0&map0:scale=75000&map0:grid_interval_x=5000&map0:grid_interval_y=5000&LAYERS=Layer1%2CLayer2%2CLayer3%2CLayerN
```

Also note that the %2C is the separator between the layers.

Comment: We can also put the project name if we want all the layers.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your question.